# TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined angular

Tags: angular

I am having difficulty in calling setInterval function.
Please find below code 
game.component.ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game',
  templateUrl: './game.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game.component.css']
})
export class GameComponent implements OnInit {
   @Output() raiseEvent: EventEmitter< {currentEvent: number} > = new EventEmitter< {currentEvent: number} >();
  currentEventCount = 1;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  StartGame() {
    setInterval( function () {
      this.raiseEvent.emit({currentEvent : this.currentEventCount++});
    }, 1000, this.raiseEvent);
  }
}
```

As per error message I think its trying to find raiseEvent in scope of setInterval, In that case how to call this function in setInterval?

Comment: the problem is the ``scope`` . so change your ``setInterval`` to ``setInterval( () =>{
      this.raiseEvent.emit({currentEvent : this.currentEventCount++});
    }, 1000, this.raiseEvent);``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use **`arrow function`** to get the value of **`this`** inside it

> - The ES6 arrow function syntax uses “lexical scoping” to figure out what the value of “this” should be. Lexical scoping is fancy way of
>     saying it uses “this” from the surrounding code… the code that
>     contains the code in question.
> - Arrow functions are anonymous and change the way this binds in functions.
> - Arrow functions simplify function scoping and the this keyword

So, `setInterval` becomes:

```
 StartGame() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.raiseEvent.emit({currentEvent : this.currentEventCount++});
    }, 1000, this.raiseEvent);
  }
```

**Without ES6 You should do something like:**

```
StartGame() {
    let self = this;
    setInterval( function () {
      self.raiseEvent.emit({currentEvent : self.currentEventCount++});
    }, 1000, self.raiseEvent);
  }
```